# Select with INNER JOIN using PostgreSQL and PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, inner-join

I'm trying to make a SELECT with INNER JOIN using two tables that share the same related field name but no success.
I have to get from the SELECT the values of the field named **taxes** where the field **type** from the table **products** are the same on the table **taxes**.

What i have at the moment that doesn't work:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT taxes
                        FROM taxes
                  INNER JOIN products
                          ON products.type = taxes.type");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? what is the error?

Comment: As my webserver is not returning explicit errors, i get nothing, a blank page that doenst show nothing on its source, that is, a error because when i comment this pice of SQL , the page shows up normally.

Comment: Did you try left join like this?  SELECT t.taxes  FROM taxes t
                  Left JOIN products p
                          ON p.type = t.type

Comment: Thank you all! It was exatcly what @kuttyraj said!!

Comment: Nice. Then my answer is correct. Have a happy coding day ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try left join like this?

```
SELECT t.taxes FROM taxes t Left JOIN products p ON p.type = t.type;
```